# Marvosym and no output PDF file produced

Tags: fonts, errors, installing-fonts

I'm learning Latex and i'm struggling to solve my problem.
Here's my code :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{pifont} %Symboles utiles et listes !
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

J'écris mon 3\up{e} document avec \og \LaTeX{} \fg.
\LaTeX{} est un langage créé par Leslie \bsc{Lamport}.

\Letter Test

\end{document}
```

When i try to compile it without using marvosym and the command \Letter everyting is ok, but when i compile the code above i got this message in the log file :

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file umvs): Font umvs at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Could someone explain me what this message means ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Welcome! It looks like you don't have `marvosym` installed or, at least, the font it needs is not configured correctly. What does `kpsewhich umvs.fd` return? And how did you install TeX?

Comment: The `marvosym.sty` file at least is there, though. Running an up-to-date distribution?

Comment: Oh well, you're right, i though i'd have the lastest package versions when i downloaded the lastest TeX distribution but some of the packages weren't up to date. I guess marvosym was using some other outdated packages.

Thank you for your help ! Have a nice day.

Comment: That's very unlikely. That message is quite specific: the font isn't found. If i had to guess, I'd say you're using MikTeX and updating coincidentally fixed the problem by updating the map files, which MikTeX has a habit of not updating after font installation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was resolved in comments, even though it isn't clear exactly what it was.